# Google Wallet payment integration in codeigniter

Tags: php, android-pay

Can Any one provide me the running code to implement google wallet ..i tried it but on setting postback url it always gives POSTBACK_ERROR while success on leaving the postback url path empty

Uh oh. There was a problem.

We couldn't complete your purchase because of a technical issue.

Details of the problem below:
Unfortunately, we could not confirm your purchase with the merchant's server. Your order has been canceled. Please contact the merchant if this problem continues.

Comment: What problems (errors, etc) did you encounter with your postback url - is it [responding proplerly](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/postback)? There are [helpful samples](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/samples#iap-php) that should get you going. Hth.

Comment: thanks for the reply that issue is resolved now but struk in another problem now....NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://www.gstatic.com/commerce/inapp/gwt/c6b2a245dd412f0efa2ddc0756b5e26a/406A7969487B881270143DF6E6B5A53A.cache.js"   but this file is not associated from my end, if you can help me then give me some suggestion

Comment: I can't repro your error, but in any case, you should be aware of [**Google Wallet for digital goods API Retirement**](https://support.google.com/wallet/business/answer/6107573)...